# Vagrant PowerVM provider?

Tags: vagrant

I am looking to see if there is already a PowerVM provider for Vagrant in order to create AIX VM's. I am curious if this is something that is already out in the community, or if one needs to be created.

If one does need to be created, does PowerVM have cli type commands like Virtualboxes VBoxManage that will ease development?

Comment: No idea. You should ask the question to Vagrant directly from `Website: http://www.vagrantup.com
IRC: #vagrant on Freenode
Mailing list: Google Groups`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure like Virtualboxes but PowerVM have cli type commands and you can connect via brouser where you will get GUI interface.